# apache exit with status 127

Tags: apache-2.2

I have just installed apache 2 with ssl but when I try to start the process I got error

`httpd starting.
exit status 127`

There is no log even though I configured httpd.conf with `LogLevel debug`. Where else can I look for clues to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Tell us more about your system. How did you install Apache and on what kind of system? Did you wrote the config files from scratch? Are there any statements in it that tell it where to log (`LogLevel` tells it how much, not where)? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html for more info regarding log files.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a standard apache error log because the service haven't started. 127 status code means that a command was not found.

How did you install apache2? Which unix distribution? What do you mean on "with ssl"?

Check on system logs found on /var/log... dmesg, messages or similar

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Apache directly rather than via the startup script.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -X -e 9 -E /var/log/httpd/startup_errors.log
```

This should give you more information.

The options I've chosen above are:

```
-e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
-E file            : log startup errors to file
-X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```